# Pandas fillna using groupby and mode

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, fillna

I recently started working with Pandas and I'm currently trying to impute some missing values in my dataset.

I want to impute the missing values based on the **median** (for numerical entries) and **mode** (for categorical entries). However, I do not want to calculate the median and mode **over the whole dataset**, but per-group, based on a `GroupBy` of my column called `"make"`.

**For numerical NA values** I did the following:

```
data = data.fillna(data.groupby("make").transform("median"))
```

...which works perfectly and replaces all my numerical `NA` values with the median of their `"make"`.

However, **for categorical NA values**, I couldn't manage to do the same thing for the mode, i.e. replace all categorical NA values with the mode of their `"make"`.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `if-else` for `median` for numeric and `mode` for categorical columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':list('ebcded'),
         'B':[np.nan,np.nan,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,np.nan,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,np.nan,1,0],
         'F':list('aaabbb'),
         'make':list('aaabbb')
})

df.loc[[2,4], 'A'] = np.nan
df.loc[[2,5], 'F'] = np.nan
print (df)
     A    B    C    D    F  make
0    e  NaN  7.0  1.0    a     a
1    b  NaN  NaN  3.0    a     a
2  NaN  4.0  9.0  5.0  NaN     a
3    d  5.0  4.0  NaN    b     b
4  NaN  5.0  2.0  1.0    b     b
5    d  4.0  3.0  0.0  NaN     b
```

---

```
f = lambda x: x.median() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x.mode().iloc[0]
df = df.fillna(df.groupby('make').transform(f))
print (df)

   A  B  C  D  F  make
0  e  4  7  1  a     a
1  b  4  7  3  a     a
2  b  4  9  5  a     a
3  d  5  4  0  b     b
4  d  5  2  1  b     b
5  d  4  3  0  b     b
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!

I tried it with your dummy data and it worked. 
Unfortunately, when I try it on my dataset I get an IndexError 'single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'.

Could this be because for some GroupBy of "make" there are only NaN values, which makes it impossible to calculate a median or a mode?

Any ideas what I could do to circumvent this problem (for example, if only NaN are in a group, then use the overall median/mode..)?

Comment: @mt1212 can you check change `x.mode(). iloc[0]` to `next(iter(x.mode()), np.nan)` ?

Comment: @jezrael: you can prevent it blowing up on groups with multiple modes by simply using `x.mode().head()`. And you can prevent it blowing up on all-NaN groups with `.mode(dropna=False).head()`

Comment: ...and you can avoid all the `np.issubdtype(...)` with [`pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)